# How to make hundreds of objects randomly stand on a curved surface(with selection area)

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to do a character's model, and this is the hair part. I want to place this cone shape short hair randomly on the back of the head (like the part in the red circle). Is there a simple way to do this instead of placing them one by one? I also try to duplicate them as a group, but since the different size and rotation, it's hard to make sure all of them are stuck into the head.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the particle system? Just create a group from those meshes and use the particle system to place them on the head mesh

Comment: @Ashok Sorry I'm new to Blender, so how to do it exactly?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZLmHnaj_A8&t=2002s watch some videos on youtube first. its hard to describe here.

Comment: @Ashok Thank you so much! This really helps!